# Не выходит получить ViewBag в ASP MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

В контроллере экшн кладёт в ViewBag динамическое свойство readOnly

```
public ActionResult Search()
    {
        ViewBag.readOnly = false;
        return View("Search");
    }
```

В самом представлении код:

```
<%if (!ViewBag.readOnly)
              {%>
                <div id="CenterButtonsBlock">
                    <input type="button" class="k-button" id="AddSelectedDonors" value="Добавить в реестр почетных доноров"/>
                </div>
            <%}%>
```

Т.е. предполагается, что присылается значение false, значит кнопка должна показываться. Если true, то кнопки не должно быть.
По факту кнопка видна всегда.

Comment: Коряво, что мешает передать модель во View?

Comment: проект не мой, просто допиливаю. Боюсь тронуть и там всё посыпится

Comment: <% var _readOnly = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.readOnly) ? false: (bool)ViewBag.readOnly; if (!_readOnly) { ...

Comment: @Дмитрий: Ну смотрите сами, ошибки в Runtime всегда хуже чем при компиляции и могут существенно доставлять проблем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде так используют его:

```
@ViewBag.readOnly
```

Comment: Это если Razor движок). Konst спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 0):

```
<% 
var _readOnly = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.readOnly) ? false:(bool)ViewBag.readOnly; 
if (!_readOnly) { ...
```